# Paypal Rails Payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

Hello you Ruby on Rails developer, i really need your help on this one..

I hire someone that promess he will install Paypal Payment, but he didnt. And i will not find him. Anyway..

I have used Ruby before, but im really a basic user, but I can read a lot, and follow guide, (if found)

My question ios

I have an APP that is basically a form, there is a formulary on 4 steps,
I just need to add a status field in Database. (active, inactive) and make a 5th step on the form , so the user can Pay, in PHP , when i do this,

Paypal IPN gives me an answer, if positive (user active) , if negative (user inactive) .. Actually i learn it from here .. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php/

Is there something similar for Rails??.. can i build a PHP step and "connect" it to a rails APP??..

Pls advaice , the plan was to buy the full and finish app on rails, why rails?, the guy who sell this told me was the fastest way, the problem Now is i dont have enough time, and i just need this to complete the work, if i change all this to PHP its gona take a lot of time

Comment: Can't help with your question, but don't worry about the choice of rails: It is a great platform for web applications!

Comment: Its so great, that i cant found explained info on how to install Payment IPN, all the documentation i found on this is short... Where can i hire a Rails Pro..?

Comment: I didn't say it has great Paypal support! Actually it probably does but I'd have no idea, sorry. I don't use Rails either. However, I did take a look at the Paypal tutorial since I need a PHP paypal service myself. See the answer below for my thoughts.

Comment: Personally I like using stripe.com for billing within rails. It seems less obtrusive as well as maintaining the same user interface as the web application.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you link to gives step-by-step instructions for configuring paypal and generating HTML code for a paypal button. All this is **completely independent of your website,** so if you are only comfortable working with PHP, as you imply, you can have your cake and eat it too: Follow the instructions, with one little modification, and code all the payment support functions in PHP.

1. Interactive: Follow steps 1, 2 and 4 to generate the raw HTML for your paypal button.
2. Rails: Once you have the HTML, you can't just "paste it into index.php", but need to embed it in your rails application. So your problem is not "how do I handle a paypal payment with Rails", but "how do I embed a fixed HTML snippet in my Rails app." Hopefully you can figure that out? I doubt anyone could help you without seeing how your app is put together.
3. PHP: The rest of the tutorial shows how to build a service that tracks payments. If you want to support the Instant Payment Notification and build a database to record payments, just follow steps 5-9 to create the service *in PHP*. Since no part of it is visible to end-users of your website, there's no need for any interaction with Rails.
4. You can ignore step 10, since you already have a working app.

Comment: Exactly!! thanks for the advaice, i am actually going this way right know.. I hope i actually can merge this...

Just one question, but i think its obvious, After this embeded html, i will need to "landing" pages after payment... Correct Payment, and Incorrect Payment, for the user, right?, but this dosent compromise security at all

Comment: Right, landing pages... I hadn't thought of that. That'd look nicer if it was just a message on the regular site, so if you can manage to code the landing pages in Rails, your php form can simply generate a redirect to one of them. No idea what you mean about security, however. Security of what? Either you receive a payment or you don't.